# "a richer, if damper, climate"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this phrase?

> In a very few hours the brown earth had become ruddy, the brick had changed to granite, and red cows grazed in well-hedged fields where the lush grasses and more luxuriant vegetation spoke of a **richer, if a damper, climate.**
>
> <sup>Source:The Hound of the Baskervilles</sup>

The end phrase of the sentence seems a bit odd. How to comprehend it?

Comment: _"...spoke of a richer climate, even if it was a damper one."_ A _richer_ climate is a better one, but a _damper_ climate is a poorer one.

Comment: +1 for learning English grammar from Sir Arthur Conan Doyle.

Answer (score 1):

The key to your questions is

> well-hedged fields where the lush grasses and more luxuriant vegetation

when vegetation is growing well "**lush**" it may imply a climate favorable for plants to *grow* ("**richer**") and since plants need *water* to grow, it tends to be "**damp**".

**Rain forests** are very "**damp**" and full of "**rich**", "**lush**" plant growth.

[image]

Comment: It's important to understand that the phrase as written implies that the richness is a positive attribute which is slightly offset by the negative attribute of dampness.

Comment: Why add **if a damper** phrase in between? What that specifically implies?